# Python PDB Issue in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, virtualenv, jupyter-lab, pdb

I am using pdb in jupyter lab but I am observing odd behavior. I am able to run pdb, however, the current line of code does not display as I step through the program. Here is an example:

```
import os
import pdb

def test():
    
    pdb.set_trace()
    a = 4
    b = 5
    
    c = a*b
    
    return c

test()
```

Running this test code and stepping through the program yields the following:

```
> c:\users\nale1\appdata\local\temp\ipykernel_17764\365146748.py(6)test()

ipdb>  n
> c:\users\nale1\appdata\local\temp\ipykernel_17764\365146748.py(7)test()

ipdb>  n
> c:\users\nale1\appdata\local\temp\ipykernel_17764\365146748.py(9)test()

ipdb>  n
> c:\users\nale1\appdata\local\temp\ipykernel_17764\365146748.py(11)test()

ipdb>  c
20
```

The debugger appears to be pointing to an incorrect location, which is what I believe may be the reason why it is not displaying the current line of code. The path in which this program is found is:

```
os.getcwd()

'C:\\Users\\nale1\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\Investments\\portfolio_construction'
```

I believe the error might be fixed if pdb is pointing to the correct location, but I'm not sure how to implement that change, nor am I sure that is actually the issue. It may also have to do with the fact that I am operating in a virtual environment. The version of python I am using is 3.8. Thank you!

Comment: This is too little information. Do you have the graphical debugger enabled? What version of ipykernel and of JupyterLab?

Comment: I don't believe I have a graphical debugger enabled, I am just using Jupyter Lab and PDB. The version of JupyterLab is 3.2.1, and ipykernel is 6.4.1.

Comment: With those versions you should be able to easily access the graphical debugger: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html

Comment: Right, I do see the graphical debugger is available, but I want the the option to stick with PDB and want to understand why it is not functioning as expected.